# Issue in Servlet with java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm using Servlets and JSP to enter a restaurant client menu into a SQL Table and it throw me the following message

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "total"

The PedidoDAO contains this:

```
public class PedidoDAO implements IPedidoDAO {


PreparedStatement ps;
private static final String SQL_INSERT  = "insert into Pedido (rutCliente, plato, bebida, despacho, total) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
private static final String SQL_READALL = "select * from Pedido";


private static final Conexion con = Conexion.getInstance();


@Override
public int Create(Pedido pedido) {

    int flag = 0;
    try {                        
        ps = con.getCnn().prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);

        ps.setString(1, pedido.getRutCliente());
        ps.setString(2, pedido.getPlato());
        ps.setString(3, pedido.getBebida());
        ps.setString(4, pedido.getDespacho());
        ps.setInt(5, pedido.getTotal());
        ps.setDate(6, fecha);
        flag = ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PedidoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return flag;

}


@Override
public ArrayList<Pedido> MostrarPedidos() {

    ArrayList<Pedido> pedidos = null;
    try {
        pedidos = new ArrayList<>();            
        ps = con.getCnn().prepareStatement(SQL_READALL);
        ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();
        while (res.next()) {
            pedidos.add(new Pedido(res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), res.getString(4), res.getInt(5)));
            System.out.println(""
                    + "Rut Cliente: "+res.getString(1)+" || "
                    + "Plato: "+res.getString(2)+" || "
                    + "Tipo Bebestible: "+res.getString(3)+" || "
                    + "Despacho?: "+res.getString(4)+" || "
                    + "Total: "+res.getInt(5));

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PedidoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return pedidos;

} 

}
```

The ADD Servlet contains this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "AgregarPedido", urlPatterns = {"/AgregarPedido"})
public class AgregarPedido extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String rut = request.getParameter("rutCliente");
        String pla = request.getParameter("nomPlato");
        String beb = request.getParameter("nomBebida");
        String domi = request.getParameter("domicilio");

        int valorTotal = 0;

        if (pla.equals("Arroz con Pollo $3200") && beb.equals("Mineral $700")) {
            valorTotal = 3900;
        } else if (pla.equals("Arroz con Pollo $3200") && beb.equals("Jugo $800")) {
            valorTotal = 4000;
        } else if (pla.equals("Arroz con Pollo $3200") && beb.equals("Malteada $1000")) {
            valorTotal = 4200;
        } else if (pla.equals("Cazuela de vacuno $3500") && beb.equals("Mineral $700")) {
            valorTotal = 4200;
        } else if (pla.equals("Cazuela de vacuno $3500") && beb.equals("Jugo $800")) {
            valorTotal = 4300;
        } else if (pla.equals("Cazuela de vacuno $3500") && beb.equals("Malteada $1000")) {
            valorTotal = 4500;
        } else if (pla.equals("Lentejas con longaniza $3000") && beb.equals("Mineral $700")) {
            valorTotal = 3700;
        } else if (pla.equals("Lentejas con longaniza $3000") && beb.equals("Jugo $800")) {
            valorTotal = 3800;
        } else if (pla.equals("Lentejas con longaniza $3000") && beb.equals("Malteada $1000")) {
            valorTotal = 4000;
        } else if (pla.equals("Porotos con riendas $2000") && beb.equals("Mineral $700")) {
            valorTotal = 2700;
        } else if (pla.equals("Porotos con riendas $2000") && beb.equals("Jugo $800")) {
            valorTotal = 2800;
        } else if (pla.equals("Porotos con riendas $2000") && beb.equals("Malteada $1000")) {
            valorTotal = 3000;
        }

        PedidoDAO pd = new PedidoDAO();
        Pedido pedido = new Pedido(rut, pla, beb, domi, valorTotal);

        pd.Create(pedido);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("ListaPedidos").forward(request, response);
```

The "List" Servlet contains this..

```
@WebServlet(name = "ListaPedidos", urlPatterns = {"/ListaPedidos"})
public class ListaPedidos extends HttpServlet {



protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

                  ArrayList<Pedido> pedidoAgregado = new ArrayList<Pedido>();

    PedidoDAO p1 = new PedidoDAO();
    pedidoAgregado = p1.MostrarPedidos();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("pedidoAgregado", pedidoAgregado);
    RequestDispatcher r = request.getRequestDispatcher("PasoDos.jsp");
    r.forward(request, response);


}
```

And the JSP contains this:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Rut</td>
            <td>Plato</td>
            <td>Bebida</td>
            <td>Despacho</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="pedidoAgregado" items="${sessionScope.pedidoAgregado}">
            <tr>

                <td>${pedidoAgregado.total}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

I don't know what is failing, because the other methods in the app like Insert User, Insert Product (Plato) are correct, but this in particular doesn't.

If you guys could help me, it would be great!

Comment: what's the column data type of 'total' in your database table?

Comment: _So much code_. Please reduce this to only the relevant code, and show us what data you're trying to parse to an integer (if that's what you're doing)

Comment: The stack trace that goes with that exception would be very valuable for locating the site of the problem.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: i cant see the "total" var...